# What does "well-known" mean in the dbus context

Tags: dbus, manual

The [dbus-daemon](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-daemon.1.html) manual makes several references to "well-known" things. Examples:

> On platforms other than Windows, unix-based transports (unix, systemd, launchd) are the default for both the well-known system bus and the well-known session bus

> This is the default for the well-known system bus and for the well-known session bus.

> Rules with the own or own_prefix attribute are checked when a connection attempts to own a well-known bus names.

I get the feeling "well-known" has a kind of legalistic meaning in the context of the manual but i cannot find any reference it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the [pydbus](https://pydbus.readthedocs.io/en/latest/legacydocs/tutorial.html#d-bus-objects) library explains it as:

> The bus name. This identifies which application you want to
> communicate with. You’ll usually identify applications by a well-known
> name, which is a dot-separated string starting with a reversed domain
> name, such as `org.freedesktop.NetworkManager` or
> `com.example.WordProcessor`.

you can see these listed if you `busctl` e.g:

```
$ busctl list
NAME                                       PID PROCESS         USER             CONNECTION    UNIT                      SESSION    DESCRIPTION        
com.redhat.NewPrinterNotification          739 applet.py       pi               :1.31         session-3.scope           3          -                  
com.redhat.PrinterDriversInstaller         739 applet.py       pi               :1.31         session-3.scope           3          -                  
fi.epitest.hostap.WPASupplicant            439 wpa_supplicant  root             :1.4          wpa_supplicant.service    -          -                  
fi.w1.wpa_supplicant1                      439 wpa_supplicant  root             :1.4          wpa_supplicant.service    -          -                  
org.bluez                                25710 bluetoothd      root             :1.370        bluetooth.service         -          -                  
org.freedesktop.Avahi                      443 avahi-daemon    avahi            :1.3          avahi-daemon.service      -          -                  
org.freedesktop.ColorManager                 - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.DBus                         1 systemd         root             -             init.scope                -          -                  
org.freedesktop.DisplayManager             532 lightdm         root             :1.6          lightdm.service           -          -                  
org.freedesktop.PackageKit                   - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1                 533 polkitd         root             :1.7          polkit.service            -          -                  
org.freedesktop.RealtimeKit1               742 rtkit-daemon    root             :1.24         rtkit-daemon.service      -          -                  
org.freedesktop.UDisks2                    432 udisksd         root             :1.5          udisks2.service           -          -                  
org.freedesktop.hostname1                    - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.locale1                      - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.login1                     423 systemd-logind  root             :1.2          systemd-logind.service    -          -                  
org.freedesktop.network1                     - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.resolve1                     - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.systemd1                     1 systemd         root             :1.1          init.scope                -          -                  
org.freedesktop.timedate1                    - -               -                (activatable) -                         -         
org.freedesktop.timesync1                  379 systemd-timesyn systemd-timesync :1.0          systemd-timesyncd.service -          -                  
org.opensuse.CupsPkHelper.Mechanism          - -               -                (activatable) -                         -
```

Answer (score 1):

D-Bus has two ways of naming "buses" (connections): *unique connection names* and *well-known bus names*.
Speaking in networking terms, *unique connection name* is like an IP address while *well-known bus name* is like a DNS entry for that. The application requests/registers *well-known bus name* and clients can later use it to find the application.

More in D-Bus specification: https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#message-protocol-names-bus